# How to deal with malformed XML with HTML character codes in lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I'm parsing a large XML file using lxml in Python 3 that has HTML character codes (e.g. `&lsqb;` and `&rsqb;`).

Here's an example of the problem and an example of my attempt to use `html.unescape()` as suggested when this was marked duplicate. I'm still struggling to make this work.  The following works, but is pretty slow and seems really hacky:

```
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
from lxml import etree
import html
import re

s = b"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tag>&lsqb;0001&rsqb;</tag>"""

def unescape(s):
    # According to this: http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html
    # There are only 4 special characters for XML.  Handle them separately.
    #
    # This site shows this other codes.
    # https://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/svlinter/How_to_use_special_characters_in_XML.3F.html
    #
    # Use temporary text that isn't likely to be in data.
    tmptxt = {b'&amp;':  ((b'&#x26;', b'&amp;', b'&#38', ), b'zZh7001HdahHq'),
              b'&lt;':   ((b'&#x3c;', b'&#60;', b'&lt', ),  b'zZh7002HdahHq'),
              b'&gt;':   ((b'&#x3e;', b'&#62;', b'&gt',),   b'zZh7002HdahHq'),
              b'&apos;': ((b'&#x27;', b'&#39;', b'&apos',), b'zZh7003HdahHq')}

    # Replace XML special chars with tmptxt
    for k, v in tmptxt.items():
        for search in v[0]:
            s = s.replace(search, v[1])

    # Use html.unescape
    s = html.unescape(s.decode()).encode()

    # replace tmptxt with the allowed XML special chars.
    for k, v in tmptxt.items():
        s = s.replace(v[1], k)

    # Get rid of any other codes and hope for the best
    regex = re.compile(rb'&[^\t\n\f <&#;]{1,32};')
    s = regex.sub(b'', s)

    return s


tree = etree.fromstring(unescape(s))

print(etree.tostring(tree))
```

The second approach that seems to work is `tree = etree.fromstring(s,  parser=etree.XMLParser(recover=True))`.  This also seems pretty slow but is obviously much cleaner.

Comment: Just in case the duplicate is not clear enough, what you need is `s = html.unescape(s) ... etree.parse(sfid)`

Comment: In other words, I have to pre-process the file first? No way around that?  Any way to html.unescape within the `lxml` parser?

Comment: I don't know. You can check by reading `lxml` documentation, which is what I would do if I were to attempt to answer that question.